# Use keyup/keydown events in JavaScript simultaneously

Tags: javascript, performance, addeventlistener, keydown, keyup

If we have dynamic information (i.e. on a Label) varying from what user has input on some text field, is it good practice to use all keyboard events to update the information as fast as possible?

Assuming we don't want to prevent any type of input, the updated information is generated in code (no services), etc.

The **keypress** is understandable, so the information isn't static between **keydown** and **keyup** events.

But if a user just press a key, the "keydown" and "keyup" events are almost simultaneously.

If the user is pressing, the "keypress" will update the information.

So, is a **keydown/keypress** or **keyup/keypress** combination enough?

Comment: And what is it that you're trying to achieve?

Comment: To know if it's worth the resources to use them all.

Comment: Could you provide an example?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using just `keyup`. It fires when the user releases the key, which I find is generally when you want to take some action. It won't fire too early (like `keydown` does).

I rarely see a use for `keydown` or `keypress`.

Comment: Yes, i normally just use keyup too, i was just wondering if it is worthy combined with keydown and do things twice for pressed key.

Comment: @Dillinger i don't think so. what advantages do you see? in my mind, no action should be taken until the key is fully pressed and released. trying to take action earlier isn't worth the trouble in my book. we're talking fractions of a second here. handling one event is way easier to manage, and it's fast enough in my experience.